# Why does at-spi-registryd.desktop warning appear every time I shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, ubuntu-mate

I have no idea what this is, can anyone help?

[image: Pop up]

Comment: Are you using "Assitive technologies" ? If not, you can disable it in the Startup Applications tool. See https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/issue-shutting-down-16-04-at-spi-registryd-desktop/5435/

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz but I did actually already disable from startup applications. I read the thread that you sent to me, I'll try disabling the actual executable and hopefully that works!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all of the 'assistive technology' stuff like at-spi2-registryd and at-spi-core cannot be removed properly, despite being disabled, without pulling out a whole load of programs. The best way i've found is to stop it from running with:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd.old
```

and

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher.old
```